# How to read mixed string and number data from csv in matlab and manipulate

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I'm looking to write a script for MATLAB that will import data from a csv file which has a first row containing string headers and the data in each of those columns is either string, date or numeric.

I want to then be able to filter the data in MATLAB according to instances of a particular string and number combination.

Any help appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to start with reading MATLAB documentation.

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx')
```

Reads numeric, text and combined data, so, if your data is combined, then you need the cell array `raw`. After that, you do whatever you want with your cell array (Additional information is not provided since OP did not provide any specific information about the way the data would be filtered)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `readtable` function in MATLAB.
It **correctly** imports csv file with header and mixed data type.

`xlsread` was imported by mixed csv file very incorrectly repeating the some rows while maintaining the same total rows.

I got this after searching for a long time:
[MATLAB Central Question/Answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/183004-how-to-read-csv-file-containing-text-and-number)